# httpapi: Why is HttpSendHttpResponse returning invalid parameter?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, http

I've tried to port http.h to Delphi, but my calls to HttpSendHttpResponse return 'invalid patameter', and I'm not sure why.

I'm sticking to HTTPAPI_V1 for now, and am testing on WinXP. I have posted source-code I use to test with here: 
http://nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?t=37904

Comment: Please post your actual code here. With only an external link to the code, the question isn't really searchable, and if the external site goes down (or away) in the future, the question is no longer useable at all. Plus, expecting people you're asking for free help to go to the extra trouble of loading another site to do so isn't quite nice. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems with it and the obvious problem was the aligning rules for the data types. Add the following to the unit to validate your data structures:

```
initialization
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_REQUEST          ) <> 464}{$message error 'HTTP_REQUEST          sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_RESPONSE         ) <> 280}{$message error 'HTTP_RESPONSE         sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_COOKED_URL       ) <>  24}{$message error 'HTTP_COOKED_URL       sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_DATA_CHUNK       ) <>  32}{$message error 'HTTP_DATA_CHUNK       sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS  ) <> 344}{$message error 'HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS  sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS ) <> 256}{$message error 'HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
  {$if sizeof( HTTP_SSL_INFO         ) <>  28}{$message error 'HTTP_SSL_INFO         sizeof error.'}{$ifend}
```

Comment: NB: if you are interested I can post the port of the code I have here (working!) but the unit is around a 1000 lines of code...

Comment: I dropped the 'packed' for the records, it got the alignment right (except for HTTP_SSL_INFO, that's only introduced in HTTPAPI v2), but it still returns the invalid parameter error code.

Comment: Indeed, alignment was the issue. I had to add {$A8}{$Z4} and totally rework HTTP_DATA_CHUNK. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!